# Django, how to implement a formfactory in my models structure?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have the following question for you. I have four models: Informazioni generali, Lavorazione, Costi_materiale and Mod. The first two give me the possibility to register "codice_commesse" and "numero_lavorazione" in this mannner:

```
class Informazioni_Generali(models.Model):
    codice_commessa= models.CharField()
    CATEGORY_CHOICES=(
    ('BOZZA', 'BOZZA'),
    ('PREVENTIVO', 'PREVENTIVO'),
    ('COMMESSA', 'COMMESSA')
    )
    status=models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    nome_cliente=models.CharField()


class Lavorazione(models.Model):
    codice_commessa=models.ForeignKey(Informazioni_Generali)
    numero_lavorazione=models.IntegerField()
    prodotto=models.ForeignKey()
    sottoprodotto=models.ForeignKey()
    note=models.CharField()
```

Once registred these two models, client have the possibility to register Costi_materiale and Mod, related to Lavorazione (itself related to Informazioni generali).

```
class Costi_materiale(models.Model):
    codice_commessa=models.ForeignKey(Informazioni_Generali, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    numero_lavorazione=models.ForeignKey(Lavorazione)
    conto = models.ForeignKey(Conto)
    tipologia = models.ForeignKey(Tipologia)
    sottocategoria = models.ForeignKey(Sottocategoria)
    quantita=models.DecimalField()
    prezzo=models.DecimalField()


class Mod(models.Model):
    codice_commessa=models.ForeignKey(Informazioni_Generali, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    numero_lavorazione=models.ForeignKey(Lavorazione, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    nome_cognome=models.CharField(')
    costo_orario=models.DecimalField()
    monte_ore=models.DecimalField()
```

I have created the model forms for Informazioni_generali and Lavorazioni, but I have problems to implement the form for the last two models. I want to have the following structure, but I don't know how to implement it. I want to fill only one time "`codice_commessa`" and "`numero_lavorazioni`" for all models related (`Costi_materiale` and `Mod`). And I want to give the possibility to the user to add new form clicking on the **"+"** button. Do you have some suggestions?

[image: ango]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow !
You need to understand that each form have a name attibute to its inputs.For Example:

```
<input type="text" name="input1">
```

The `name` attribute of input allows the view(backend) to handle each input separately inside a `POST` or `GET` request.Hence the name should be unique.

If the `name` for two inputs is same , you will get a MUltiKeyError.

You can achieve what you want but for that you have to handle the extra inputs by yourself and the Model Form won't do that for you.
First of all you need to generate the Input fields which can be done using Javascript.

Inside your already existing form tag you have the button + ,Attach an onclick attribute to it like this:

```
<form id="DynamicForm">  
     <button onclick="AddInput()"></button>
</form>
```

Also give your form and id attribute to get it in Javascript.

In an attached script or Inline Script tag you can add JS code like this:

```
<script>
        var counter = 0;
     function AddInput(){
       let h = '<input type="text" name="input'+counter+'">';
       var d = document.getElementById('DynamicForm');
       d.insertadjacenthtml('beforeend',h);
       counter = counter+1;
    }
 </script>
```

Then you need to access these input fields in view which you can do by using :

```
    ....
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ModelFormName(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          data = form.cleaned_data['input1']
       else:
           #FormInvalid Error 
    else:
        #NotValid Request Method
    ....
```

Now you might want to know how many inputs the user added, for that you can use the same counter variable and add another input named `new_input_len` with value set to highest value that counter achieved.
Then use that input value to iterate through a for loop in your back-end and access all the added inputs.